# Is it possible to parameterize a JUnit Jupiter test with beans from a Spring ApplicationContext?

Tags: spring, dependency-injection, junit5, parameterized

I would like to write a unit test which is executed for every Spring bean of a given type. JUnit5's parameterized tests offer a lot of possibilities, but I don't know how to inject beans into a method source as it has to be a static method.

Is there a way to determine the parameters of a JUnit5 test based on Spring's application context?

Comment: You could just inject the context and use the Spring Bean's names as parameters and do the lookup in some kind of setup code.

Comment: But the bean names have to be a static list?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

For starters, a factory method configured via `@MethodSource` does not have to be `static`. The second sentence in the [User Guide](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#writing-tests-parameterized-tests-sources-MethodSource) explains that.

> Factory methods within the test class must be `static` unless the test class is annotated with `@TestInstance(Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)`; whereas, factory methods in external classes must always be `static`.

Thus, if you use `@TestInstance(PER_CLASS)` semantics, your `@MethodSource` factory method can be non-static and can therefore access the `ApplicationContext` injected into the test instance.

Here's an example that demonstrates that for beans of type `String`, with an intentional failure for the `bar` bean.

```
import java.util.stream.Stream;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.TestInstance;
import org.junit.jupiter.params.ParameterizedTest;
import org.junit.jupiter.params.provider.MethodSource;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringJUnitConfig;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals;
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.TestInstance.Lifecycle.PER_CLASS;

@SpringJUnitConfig
@TestInstance(PER_CLASS)
class SpringBeansParameterizedTests {

    @Autowired
    ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    @ParameterizedTest
    @MethodSource
    void stringBeans(String bean) {
        assertEquals(3, bean.length());
    }

    Stream<String> stringBeans() {
        return applicationContext.getBeansOfType(String.class).values().stream();
    }

    @Configuration
    static class Config {

        @Bean
        String foo() {
            return "foo";
        }

        @Bean
        String bar() {
            return "barf";
        }
    }
}
```

If you don't want to work directly with the `ApplicationContext`, you can simplify the solution by having the collection of all such beans of a given type (`String` in this example) injected directly, as follows.

```
@SpringJUnitConfig
@TestInstance(PER_CLASS)
class SpringBeansParameterizedTests {

    @Autowired
    List<String> stringBeans;

    @ParameterizedTest
    @MethodSource
    void stringBeans(String bean) {
        assertEquals(3, bean.length());
    }

    Stream<String> stringBeans() {
        return this.stringBeans.stream();
    }

    @Configuration
    static class Config {

        @Bean
        String foo() {
            return "foo";
        }

        @Bean
        String bar() {
            return "barf";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Wonderfully detailed answer. Thanks for putting it together.

Answer (score 0):

The usage of the `@TestFactory` might help.

Actually I stumbled across a post that does a pretty similar (or the same) thing as you do on [github](https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/issues/378#issuecomment-367964922).

Let your Test run with the `SpringExtenion` and use the injected Beans as parameters for our Test.